# How to get the whole components tree in jest and testing-library/react-native?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I have a component that I am testing using jest and react native testing library
that looks something like this :

```js
<FallbackErrorBoundary>
  <Wrapper>
    <Component1>
      <Component2>

      </Component2>

    </Component1>
  </Wrapper>
 </FallbackErrorBoundary>
```

I want to get the whole rendered tree , I tried using

```
renderedComponent.container.children
```

But It only gets the direct children  (FallbackErrorBoundary)

I tried using  `expect(renderedComponent).toMatchSnapshot()`
but It's not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prettyDOM](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#prettydom) or [asFragment](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#asfragment)

E.g.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/react'

const HelloWorld = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>
const {container, } = render(<HelloWorld />)
const treeString = prettyDOM(container);
console.log(treeString)
// <div>
//   <h1>Hello World</h1>
// </div>

expect(asFragment()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
  <DocumentFragment>
    <h1>
      Hello World
    </h1>
  </DocumentFragment>
`);
```

If you don't want `DocumentFragment` element, you can use `asFragment().firstChild`.